# How would you define the set of all real-valued functions that have a continuous nth derivative, using set-builder notation?

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, vector-spaces

I'm trying to prove this exercise:

"Let $C^n(\mathbb R)$ denote the set of all real-valued functions defined on the
real line that have a continuous nth derivative. Prove that $C^n(\mathbb R))$ is a
subspace of $F(\mathbb R,\mathbb R)$. Where $F(\mathbb R,\mathbb R)$ is the set of all functions from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$."

But I'm having issues at defining the set $C^n(\mathbb R)$ in a $C^n(\mathbb R):=\{ \}$ way, since the text only defines it in words.

My best attempt is this (I'm not sure if it's correct):
$C^n(\mathbb R)$ in a $C^n(\mathbb R):=\{f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R\, |\, \forall f \in \mathbb R, \exists \, f^n  \}$

Comment: Do you need to write it in set-builder notation? You can but it isn't necessary to show $C^n(\mathbb{R})$ has the subspace properties.

Comment: Yes, our professor told us to write it in a set-builder notation, and that's the part where I'm having issues.

Comment: Hmm, maybe something like $\{f \in F(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}) | (\forall x\in \mathbb{R})( \forall (x_k)\to x)( f^{(n)}(x_k)\to f^{(n)}(x)) \}$?

Comment: Yes! Tbh I thought that it had to be written in a limit notation, but this works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @george_p: by (rigorous) definition, a real variable real valued function $f$ is of class $\mathrm{C}^n$ if there exists a family $g$ of $\mathit{continuous}$ real variable real valued functions indexed by the $\mathit{natural}$ interval $[0, n]$ such that $g_0＝f$ and for every $k<n$ $g_k$ is derivable, satisfying the relation $g_{k＋1}＝g'_k$. A recursive definition, in other words. It is easily seen that given a function $f$ at most one family $g$ such as above can exist and when it does the final member $g_n$ is by definition the $n$-th derivative $f^{(n)}$.